# How to implement load balancer in tomcat when 2 tomcats are in different machines?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, load-balancing

I have a web application which runs on 32 bit JDK and tomcat. This web application is intermittently crashing with OOMs and timeouts waiting for connection pool threads. So i am trying to install the application in 2 different tomcats on 2 different machines. 2 different machines so that more heap space will be available to help with the OOM.

Requirement is to direct the user to freely available tomcat when there are multiple parallel sessions in progress.

After reading about load balancing vs clustering, it looks like load balancing might be more suitable as i want all the requests from a user session to go to the same tomcat. Is this correct understanding?

however, clustering and load balancing do not seem to be supporting tomcats on 2 different machines. I need tomcats on different machines so that the application(JVM) can utilize more memory.

More reading resulted in more confusion in terms on "terracotta", "memcached", "session replication" etc.

It would be highly helpful if someone can point me in the right direction on what a possible solution can be in terms on increasing the resources the web application can utilize.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/637303/scaling-a-web-application-horizontally-in-tomcat-load-balancing-clustering Do you need state replication between the two machines?

Comment: Try using nginx as a front facade, who redirects the requests to Tomcat running at the backend. For sessions, new versions of tomcat supports sharing sessions via Redis.

Comment: yes, state replication will be needed I suppose. If users in 2 sessions are writing to that same db table, that case has to be handled

Comment: @user811433 Users in two sesssions writing to the same database has nothing to do with it. You Your webapp has to handle that anyway. The central issue is that you need the sessions to be 'sticky', i.e. always be directed to the original Tomcat except on failover, and replicated so that failover is seamless to the user. However what you should *really* do is fix the bugs in your webapp. Replication is for scalability, not bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very easily with Apache HTTPD and its `mod_proxy_loadbalancer`. I've had a configuration like this running for years. It can do session stickiness and all that, and you can control it dynamically at runtime.

Comment: I am currently trying to run this setup of HTTPD+mod_jk+tomcat on windows. I have one question. My web application deployed in tomcat can be accessed via https. If I am now using HTTPD to route all access to the application, how can I setup HTTPD to support HTTPS requests to my application in Tomcat? Does mod_jk support this or do I need to use a different tomcat connector?

Comment: You only need JK (or AJP: see below) plaintext between HTTPD and Tomcat. I would remove the HTTP/HTTPS connectors from Tomcat altogether so that HTTP/S access is only via HTTPD. I would also use mod_ajp rather than mod_jk: it is much easier to configure, for one thing, with an AJP connector at the Tomcat end and no other Tomcat-side configuation required at all.